How to search in the array and find corresponding value
I have 2 rows of data - Column A containing "Equipment ID", and Column B containing # of each ID. The Macro below provided by @FaneDuru is below:
Sub ExtractMaxPerEquipment()
 Dim ws As Worksheet, lastR As Long, arr, arrFin, i As Long, dict As Object
 
 Set ws = ActiveSheet 'use here the necessary sheet
 lastR = ws.Range("A" & ws.rows.count).End(xlUp).row 'last row in A:A
 
 arr = ws.Range("A2:B" & lastR).Value2 'place the range in an array for faster processing
 
 Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary") 'set the necessary dictionary
 For i = 1 To UBound(arr) 'iterate between the array rows
    dict(arr(i, 1)) = Application.Max(endNo(CStr(arr(i, 2))), dict(arr(i, 1))) 'load the dictionary
 Next i
 
 arrFin = Application.Transpose(Array(dict.keys, dict.Items)) 'combine the dictionary keys and items in an array
 
 ws.Range("D2").Resize(UBound(arrFin), 2).Value2 = arrFin 'drop the final array content in "D2"
End Sub

Function endNo(x As String) As String
    If x = "" Then endNo = 0: Exit Function
    With CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
        .Pattern = "\d{1,5}?.*$"
        .Global = False
        endNo = .Execute(x)(0)
    End With
End Function


Currently, it creates a table of all the unique Equipment IDs and Highest number for each in Column D and E, respectively. I need to search within this array - for example, I have an string called "Asset" - I need the macro to be modified to search for Asset in the "Equipment Name" of the Array and return the corresponding highest value. How do I do that?

What have you tried to adapt the given code to your needs?

I modified it to paste the data in a separate sheet, and search for the "Asset" that I need to find and copy the corresponding value with this formula
`Set aCell = Sheets("DropDowns").Columns("J:K").Find(What:=Asset, After:="a1", LookIn:=xlFormulas2, _
LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
currentSN = Trim(aCell.Offset(0, 1))
MsgBox currentSN'`
but that didn't seem to work

Please don't post code in the comments, edit your question instead.

What was the problem with your code? For one thing, the code you post here is NOT searching for the string Asset. Rather it is searching for whatever you have stored in the variable you have named Asset. So if Asset does not contain the string, your function will fail.

Searching by Equipment Name simplifies the script, eliminating the need to use a Dict object
Sub Demo()
    Dim i As Long
    Dim arrData, rngData As Range, iVal As Long
    Dim MaxVal As Long
    Const EQU_NAME = "Asset"
    Set rngData = ActiveSheet.Range("A1").CurrentRegion
    arrData = rngData.Value
    For i = LBound(arrData) + 1 To UBound(arrData)
        If arrData(i, 1) = EQU_NAME Then
            iVal = Val(endNo(CStr(arrData(i, 2))))
            If iVal > MaxVal Then MaxVal = iVal
        End If
    Next i
    If MaxVal = 0 Then
        MsgBox "Can't find max value for " & EQU_NAME
    Else
        MsgBox "Max Value is " & MaxVal
    End If
End Sub
' script from OP
Function endNo(x As String) As String
    If x = "" Then endNo = 0: Exit Function
    With CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
        .Pattern = "\d{1,5}?.*$"
        .Global = False
        endNo = .Execute(x)(0)
    End With
End Function


I have in mind what you required in a comment to my answer at your previous question. I do not know if you do not need that part, anymore, or you want doing it by yourself if you understand how to deal with a specific equipment.
The next piece of code should be copied in the sheet code module where the data to be processed exists.
It will automatically create in B:B a serial number of the pattern "SN009", incrementing the maximum existing numeric part for the respective Equipment name. Or creating "SN001" for a new equipment name:
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.column = 1 And Target.row > 1 Then
        Dim i As Long, arr, dict As Object
        If Target.Value <> "" Then
            arr = Range("A2:B" & Target.row - 1).Value2
            Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
            dict.CompareMode = TextCompare 'string comparison is not case sensitive...
            For i = 1 To UBound(arr)
                If UCase(Target.Value) = UCase(arr(i, 1)) Then
                    dict(arr(i, 1)) = Application.Max(endNo(CStr(arr(i, 2))), dict(arr(i, 1)))
                End If
            Next i
            Application.EnableEvents = False
             If dict.count > 0 Then
                Target.Offset(, 1).Value = "SN" & Format(dict(Target.Value) + 1, "00#") 'incremented maximum existing
             Else
                Target.Offset(, 1).Value = "SN001" 'in case of a new equimpent name
             End If
            Application.EnableEvents = True
        Else
            Application.EnableEvents = False
                Target.Offset(, 1).Value = ""
            Application.EnableEvents = True
        End If
    End If
End Sub

Private Function endNo(x As String) As Long
    If x = "" Then endNo = 0: Exit Function
    With CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
        .Pattern = "\d{1,4}?.*$"
        .Global = False
        endNo = .Execute(x)(0)
    End With
End Function

No need to accept the answer, even it is helpful. I had in mind your need (as I understood) and only try helping with an example piece of code. It can be improved to process only the last record, but this is a different issue...

You don't need VBA to accomplish this task, this seems to me like a rather old-school way of doing things. Using the new version of Excel you can achieve the same result using a formula which is faster and easier to maintain.  To get the same result as from your current VBA code you can use something like (which can no doubt be simplified even further):
=LET(
    data, B2:B11,
    names, A2:A11,
    extractDigits, LAMBDA(cell, IFERROR(VALUE(TEXTJOIN("", TRUE, IFERROR(MID(cell, SEQUENCE(LEN(cell)), 1) + 0, ""))), 0)),
    digits, MAP(data, extractDigits),
    uniqueNames, UNIQUE(names),
    maxValues, MAP(uniqueNames, LAMBDA(name, MAX(FILTER(digits, names=name)))),
    HSTACK(uniqueNames, maxValues)
) 

and if you need to filter/search within the output you can do so using the FILTER function.

